# IPHONE ble connect to ANDROID

Tags: android, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

i use swift to write bluetooth,I want iPhone connect Android

but i use Corebluetooth `self.centralManager?.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)` can't find android device,android bluetooth use this [bluetooth chat](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat)

And how can i let iPhone be scan..in android `ensureDiscoverable();`

Comment: That app is using RFCOMM, not BLE, so it won't be seen by an iOS app using CBCentralManager.  Core Bluetooth can only be used with BLE.

Comment: Thx!, IF i use RFCOMM in swift that can connect to Android ?

Comment: @Paulw11was correct and if you want to do that, you may need implement GATT server on your android phone side. Just search GATT server sample code on stackoverflow. the Android developer site does not provide such code.

Comment: No, you should use MFi chip in case you connect RFCOMM with iPhone, and this chip absolutely does not exists on your android phone.

Comment: Ok,so if my iPhone need discoverable device i need use MFi chip..so only android can discoverable